# python exec() unexpected indent in loop

Tags: python, loops, exec

What is the workaround for "Unexpected Indent" error from this?

```
In [15]: def f(x): 
    ...:     return x 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                        

In [16]: for i in range (10): 
    ...:     exec(f""" 
    ...:     v_{i} = f(i) 
    ...:     """)
```

Comment: You're putting spaces at the beginning of the `v_` line. Since it's not inside a loop in the `exec()` function, it shouldn't be indented.

Comment: Also, don't do this.  Use a dictionary.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Answer (score 1):

Don't indent the line with the `v_{i}` assignment.

```
In [16]: for i in range (10): 
    ...:     exec(f""" 
    ...: v_{i} = f(i) 
    ...:     """)
```

The code executed by `exec()` doesn't inherit the indentation of the calling code. So that statement needs to be at the beginning of the line since you're not execing a loop.

There isn't really a need for a multi-line string in the first place, you can just do:

```
exec(f'v_{i} = f(i)')
```

Of course, this whole thing is misguided. Dynamic variable names are generally a bad idea, you should be using a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the indentation error by rewriting the parameter of the exec function you call to span only one line instead of multiple.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `exec`to creating 10 variables and assigning the values of f(0) to f(9).

The `exec` block needs to be indented one level to the right, relative to the `for` loop.

```
def f(x):
    return x

for i in range(10):
    exec(f"""
v_{i} = f(i)
""")
```